# Scrollify - multiple functions in "before"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-scrollify

I'm trying to add some animations to website which is running scrollify. It would be nice to add it to the "before" parameter. Before looks like this :

```
$(function() {   $.scrollify({
    section:".panel",
    scrollbars:true,
    setHeights:false,
    **before:function(i,panels) {
      var ref = panels[i].attr("data-section-name");
      $(".pagination .active").removeClass("active");
      $(".pagination").find("a[href=\"#" + ref + "\"]").addClass("active");    
    },**
    afterRender:function() {
      var pagination = "<ul class=\"pagination\">";
      var activeClass = "";
      $(".panel").each(function(i) {
        activeClass = "";
        if(i===0) {
          activeClass = "active";
        }
        pagination += "<li><a class=\"" + activeClass + "\" href=\"#" + 
$(this).attr("data-section-name") + "\"><span class=\"hover-text\">" + $(this).attr("data-section-name").charAt(0).toUpperCase() + $(this).attr("data-section-name").slice(1) + "</span></a></li>";
      });

      pagination += "</ul>";

      $(".home").append(pagination);
      $(".pagination a").on("click",$.scrollify.move);
    },   }); });
```

I would like to add code below to function in "before" parameter above. It starts with " **before:function(i,panels) {" I don't know how to merge those two functions together. I hope that's clear now.

```
function(section) {
  if (section === 0) {
    $('.home h1').addClass("fadeIn");
  }

  if (section !== 0) {
    $('.home h1').removeClass("fadeIn");
  }

  if (section === 1) {
    $('.panel1 h1').addClass("slideInUp");
  }

  if (section !== 1) {
    $('.panel1 h1').removeClass("slideInUp");
  }
},
```

Comment: fix your question's codes

Comment: Hi, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Give your second function a name and call it in the `before` callback.

Comment: Hi Luke, and how do I do that?

Comment: I'd recommend reading up on JavaScript functions: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: Thanks Luke. Will do.